# Save canvas as image into database with jquery and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, canvas

So, I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong in my code. I have a `<canvas>` element which can be drawn on. On `mouseup` jQuery pulls the data as an image and should then post it to PHP, which stores it in the database. It's not working though.

```
function print(){
    var canvas1 = document.getElementById("paint");
    var ctx1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");
    var img = canvas1.toDataURL("image/png");
    img = encodeURIComponent(img);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'poster.php',
        data: { data: img },
                type: 'post',
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
    });
```

**poster.php**

```
<?php

    $data = $_POST['data'];

    $server = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "root";
    $database = "canvas";
    $bd = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die("1");
    $ok = mysql_select_db($database, $bd) or die("2");

    $sql = "INSERT INTO canvas (image) VALUES ($data)";
    $qry = mysql_query($sql);

    echo $qry;

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do **var_dump()** in your poster.php script to see if your ajax is feeding it something.
Then modify the following:

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO canvas (image) VALUES ($data)";
    $qry = mysql_query($sql);
```

to:

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO canvas (image) VALUES ($data)";
    if( ! mysql_query($sql) )
   {
       echo "Error: " . mysql_error();
   }
```

Maybe output from the above will show the way to go!

Comment: It does post it, but the php script throws this error: `Error: Unknown column 'data%3Aimage%2Fpng%3Bbase64%2CiVBORw0KGgoAAA' in 'field list'string(5217) "INSERT INTO canvas (image) VALUES`

Comment: What type of data definition is the "image" column in your database? (Don't forget that file uploads is available to php as $_FILES superglobal variable)